# Compare two arrays and find the nearest result

Tags: python-3.x

So, I have this exercise where I have to find the nearest pharmacy from the coordinate inputted by the user, but i don't know how to.
I have a file with the coodinates from each pharmacy, like this:

```
300 200
10 56
25 41
90 18
70 90
100 50
```

And when the user input his coordinate ("20 88" in the example) i should tell him the coordinate from the nearest one. I'll write what I already have, but my codes are in Brazilian Portuguese, so i hope you can help me.

```
# Sub-programa
def fazTudo():
    dados = open("texto.txt", "r")
    linha = dados.readline()
    if linha == "":
        return "Arquivo de Farmácias está vazio!!!"
    else:
        for i in range(6):
            distancia = []
            vetor = dados.readline()
            x, y = vetor.split()
            distanciaX = x
            distanciaY = y
            distancia = distanciaX, distanciaY

# Programa Principal
entrada = (input().split(" "))
fazTudo()
```

Comment: The first step would be to compute a number that is the distance for each point based on the origin and then take the points that have the smallest distance...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the current stage you're at is reading the distances from the file.

From there, what you would want to do is find compare the users inputted location to the location of each pharmacy. Finding the smallest displacement in both the X and Y co-ordinates should get you the closest pharmacy. But since you want distance, you would want to convert the displacement value to distance by getting the absolute.

Here is a solution that I thought of:

```
# Find the closest distance to the pharmacies from a text file.
def closest_distance(raw_input_location):
    nearest_pharmacy = [0, 0]

    user_x_y = raw_input_location.split(" ")

    with open("filename.txt") as f:
        locations = f.read().splitlines()

    if not locations:
        return "Pharmacy list is empty!!!"
    else:
        for index, row in enumerate(locations):
            x_y = row.split(" ")
            delta_x = abs(int(user_x_y[0]) - int(x_y[0]))
            delta_y = abs(int(user_x_y[1]) - int(x_y[1]))
            if index == 0:
                nearest_pharmacy[0] = delta_x
                nearest_pharmacy[1] = delta_y
            elif delta_x < nearest_pharmacy[0] & delta_y < nearest_pharmacy[0]:
                nearest_pharmacy[0] = delta_x
                nearest_pharmacy[1] = delta_y
    # Returns the distance required to goto the closest pharmacy
    return str(nearest_pharmacy[0]) + " " + str(nearest_pharmacy[1])

# Prints out the closest distance from the inputted location
print(closest_distance("20 88"))
```